# visualize matrix with individual datapoints

Tags: r, visualization

I usually like to visualize my data using boxplots in R.
Lately, I have been working a lot with high-dimensional Likert-scale data (0-3 or 0-7), with rather few observations (maybe 200).
So I am looking for a way to effectively get a visual overview of the data, but find my usual go-to boxplot-matrix insufficient as I would rather see the individual data points.

I know that boxplots can be overlaid with for example ggplot2 and jitter, but that's also not what I'm looking for.
Does anyone have a simple solution on how to visualize the individual data points per variable of a matrix?

So given

```
B = matrix( 
  c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 6, 2), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=5)
 boxplot.matrix(B)
```

How could I instead plot the data points together with lines representing median and IQR for all the variables in my matrix?
Thanks!

[image: boxplots]

[image]

Comment: You could add more tags on what technologies/languages you plan to use etc so this question doesn't pop all over?

Comment: Sorry, i was so in my head that I didnt think of that

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "plot the data points together with lines representing median and IQR..."? As you mentioned that boxplots with overlaid `ggplot2` `jitter` is not what you want? Do you mean you want the overlay, but without jitter?

Comment: I added two pictures now. One is the result of boxplot.matrix(B) in R, the other two were done in graphpad prism. What I want is to make a plot similar to the second one that shows all individual datapoints but for every column of a matrix in R (as I want to stay in one program for all analysis). Also a line showing the median (like in the second picture, and if possible the IQR). So basically: Plot all datapoints of each column next to each other and display median and maybe IQR with lines.

Comment: Those are called beeswarms. There is a package called [ggbeeswarm](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm). Draw the medians with `stat_summary`.

Comment: Thanks  @Axeman, this really helps. But I still have a problem: Looking at the example  ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_beeswarm()  here they plot the three species by petal length. What i want to do is just plot every column in my matrix without using groups or comparing groups. I cannot get how to call for that.

Comment: Then you need to reshape using e.g. tidyr::gather

Comment: Why @Axeman?  
 "Gather takes multiple columns and collapses into key-value pairs, duplicating all other columns as needed. You use gather() when you notice that you have columns that are not variables." I have one column per variable and one row per observation. And I just want to plot every column next to each other in a big graph similar to boxplot.matrix does. So basically I want to know what every one of my patients scores for each measure, in one graph. So I dont know what to add as y-variable foe aes?

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, you need to reshape first, because then you can map the variable name to `x` and the value to `y`.

This is because the design of `ggplot2`, where you need to map one aesthetic to one column, i.e. you can't put several columns on the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

B_df <- as.data.frame(B)
B_long <- tidyr::gather(B_df)

ggplot(B_long, aes(key, value)) + geom_beeswarm()
```

[image]

Of course, you don't have quite enough data to make this look good.

Here's a slightly better example, including median lines:

```
fr_long <- tidyr::gather(freeny)
ggplot(fr_long, aes(key, value)) + 
  geom_beeswarm() +
  stat_summary(aes(ymin = ..y.., max = ..y..), fun.y = 'mean', geom = 'crossbar', color = 'firebrick')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. This greatly helps me to understand ggplot2 in general.I have upvoted your answer but it doesn't take effect until I myself have enough points.